# Active Users in application from Active Directory and related with column email in table Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ado.net, azure-active-directory

i have a web application. basically for log in this app, i use username and password from local database.
now, i want log in with Active directory our company and sync with email in model.email from table user.
so, active users :

**Example**

```
var objek = !HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == model.email.FirstOrDefault();

Session["userActive"] = objek;
```

may someone can help with right code?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge:

1. HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is a boolean value.
2. model.email.FirstOrDefault() would be a string value.

I do not think a boolean value can be compared to a string. The code will not pass the compile.

By the way, you said you wanted to log in with Active directory and synced with email in model.email from table user.

So my questions are:

1. Is your AD a on-premise AD or Azure AD?
2. If a user log in with AD, then what the table user is? Does he need to log in again with his local username and password?
3. For "sync with", what do you really want to approach?

Could you please describe your issue in detail, so that we can help you further.

Comment: hi jack, thanks for your respond.
actually, i want this apps login with double check authentication (from form login),
first, with LDAP ActiveDirectory from my domain organization (domain username and password),
and then second authentication  with database table (sync username from AD and username in database table).
so the active user is from database table.

thanks.